# I tried to create a simple string parser but my code doesn't work

Tags: c++, parsing

I tried to create this string parser, but the code emit unintended result. The code receives input from `std::getline()` then passing it to the function. It would return a `std::vector<std::string>`. Then for testing purpose, I try to print out (using `std::cout`) each value from the vector and it doesn't seem to work.

What I'm trying to do is to separate each words except words within two double-quotes.

The input given: `Hello -c -v "Hello World!" -exec -str "Hello" -ps`

The output:

```
Hello -c -v Hello
World!
 -exec -str Hello
 -ps
```

Expected result:

```
Hello
-c
-v
Hello World!
-exec
-str 
Hello
-ps
```

Here's the function:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string str) {
    std::vector<std::string> internal;

    std::size_t last_quote = -1;
    std::string bin;

    for (std::size_t i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        if (str[i] == '"') {
            if (last_quote == -1) last_quote = i;
            else {
                last_quote = -1;
                internal.push_back(bin);
                bin = "";
            }
        } else if (str[i] == ' ' && last_quote != -1) {
            internal.push_back(bin);
            bin = "";
        } else {
            bin.push_back(str[i]);
        }
        if (i == str.length()-1) internal.push_back(bin);
    }

    return internal;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: What should the _expected_ output look like? I can guess what you want, but it would be good if you could clarify.

Comment: I'm expecting 'Hello' '-c' '-v' 'Hello
World!'
 '-exec' '-str' 'Hello'
'-ps'

Comment: One problem I see: `std::size_t` is an _unsigned_ data type, so assigning `-1` is not going to have the result you expect. Maybe work with `std::string::size_type` and `std::string::npos` instead.

Comment: Seems in `} else if (str[i] == ' ' && last_quote != -1) {` should be `last_quote == -1` also

Comment: @TitoNovelianto can you please edit the question to include the expected result? It'll make it easier for us to help.

Comment: @timocov It's looking if there is a space and if there was a double-quote before... :)

Comment: Yes, and you should add it if there is no double quotes before - `last_index == -1`

Comment: @mindriot: I have replaced all `-1` related with the variable `last_quote` using `std::string::npos`, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine, but add empty string which come after last double quota

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string str)
{
    std::vector<std::string> internal;

    std::size_t last_quote = -1;
    std::string bin;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '"')
        {
            if (last_quote == -1) last_quote = i;
            else
            {
                last_quote = -1;
                internal.push_back(bin);
                bin = "";
            }
        }
        else if (str[i] == ' ' && last_quote == -1)
        {
            internal.push_back(bin);
            bin = "";
        }
        else
        {
            bin.push_back(str[i]);
        }
        if (i == str.length() - 1) internal.push_back(bin);
    }

    return internal;
}
```

There is output for your example string:

```
Hello
-c
-v
Hello World!

-exec
-str
Hello

-ps
```